# DS-5 - How to view the value of a NEON register?

Tags: arm, neon, ds-5

I am using ARM DS-5 and I cannot see NEON registers in the normal register view. I can only see the core registers. Any idea on how I can see the NEON registers?

Comment: http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/ds-5-documentation/arm-ds-5-debugger-user-guide/registers-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DS-5 displays only the core registers by default. To display NEON and other system registers, you have to manually add them by either clicking the `Browse` Button or typing the name of register in the text box beside `Browse` button.

Detailed documentation is available at http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/ds-5-documentation/arm-ds-5-debugger-user-guide/registers-view